# Where does 'res' come from in 'https.request'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, playwright, asynccallback

```
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(res);

  res.on("data", (d) => { // Same thing here
    console.log(d);
  });
});
```

How does this function know to fill that res parameter with the response object, and how does it do it? I could put there any function, but only in this syntax it works like this.

```
function callback(res) {
  console.log(res);
}
```

If i define a function like this, and pass it as callback to https.request it won't work as expected.

How does this thing work?

(Note that I'm testing this with a playwright test file, don't know if it can affect the situation)

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Comment: Yes it would work: `const req = https.request(options, callback)`

Comment: `res.on("data", callback)` too